# How to tell Pipenv ignore a package in Pipfile based on the OS

Tags: python, pipenv

I am creating a Python project using Pipenv and I have the following Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
black = "==19.10b0"
pylint = "==2.4.4"
pytest = "==5.3.1"
pytest-mock = "==1.13.0"
pytest-flask = "==0.15.0"

[packages]
python-decouple = "==3.3"
pytz = "*"
Flask = "==1.1.1"
Flask-RESTful = "==0.3.7"
uWSGI = "==2.0.18"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

My problem is that the `uWSGI` package is only available for Linux and I am using Windows. So whenever I run `pipenv install` it fails because of it. Is there a way to tell Pipenv to ignore the installation of this package only on a Windows environment?

**UPDATE**

Here is the result of the command: `pipenv lock -r`

```
Pipfile.lock (e1b4e4) out of date, updating to (5696f6)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Success!
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Locking Failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 118, in main
    _main(parsed.pre, parsed.clear, parsed.verbose, parsed.system,
  File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 78, in _main
    results = resolve(
  File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 61, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 718, in resolve_deps
    resolved_tree, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 385, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 102, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round
    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 301, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\resolve.py", line 211, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 294, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 470, in run_egg_info
    call_subprocess(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 703, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\FELIPE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuyfdyzgwbuild\uwsgi\
File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 118, in main
    _main(parsed.pre, parsed.clear, parsed.verbose, parsed.system,
  File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 78, in _main
    results = resolve(
  File "c:/users/felipe a/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 61, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 718, in resolve_deps
    resolved_tree, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 385, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 102, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round
    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 301, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\resolve.py", line 211, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 294, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 470, in run_egg_info
    call_subprocess(
  File "c:\users\felipe a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 703, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\FELIPE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuyfdyzgwbuild\uwsgi\
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

besides the version, you can pass the environment/os in the Pipenv file.

For your example (with having uWSGI only on linux):

`uWSGI = {version = "*", sys_platform = "== 'linux'"}`

You can check the `sys_platform` with:

```
import sys
print(sys.platform) #python3
```

If you have the sys platform (eg `win32` or `linux`) you can add the `sys_platform` in your Pipenv file as described above

This should solve your issue

**EDIT**:

uWSGI has currently an issue with Windows integration:

> Pipenv needs to run setup.py to inspect dependencies from a source
>   distribution. You will need to ask uWSGI to release a wheel, or at
>   least make setup.py egg_info work on Windows (the library itself does
>   not need to work, only setup.py).
>   *from [github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3084](http://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3084)*

With this code you can make a workaround I tried it and it works:

```
# make pipenv lock uwsgi works under windows
# add func to os.py in virtualenv

def uname():
    import inspect
    caller = inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[1][0]).__name__
    if caller == 'uwsgiconfig':
        return ("", "", "", "", "")
    raise AttributeError()
```

*code from[gist.github.com/hulucc/669b3f9cc379f017840285fb2bed3387](http://gist.github.com/hulucc/669b3f9cc379f017840285fb2bed3387) *

Comment: Hi, I changed my Pipfile to this: `uWSGI = {version = "==2.0.18", sys_platform = "== 'linux'"}`, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: can you give me the output of `pipenv lock -r` (file)

Comment: I've updated the question with the output you requested

Comment: ah yes i see the issue, `Pipenv needs to run setup.py to inspect dependencies from a source distribution. You will need to ask uWSGI to release a wheel, or at least make setup.py egg_info work on Windows (the library itself does not need to work, only setup.py).`  with this code you can make a workaround I tried it and it works: https://gist.github.com/hulucc/669b3f9cc379f017840285fb2bed3387
See this as reference: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3084 - I know there are open PR's for pipenv uwgsi windows compatibility.

Comment: It seems there are more open bugs about it but its uwsgi related not pipenv. https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/3355

Comment: Hi, I added this code: https://gist.github.com/hulucc/669b3f9cc379f017840285fb2bed3387 to my virtual env and it worked. I was able to lock the uWSGI. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with `bjoern`, which does not support Windows.

The working syntax for me is:

`bjoern = {version = "*", markers="sys_platform == 'linux'"}`

It shows a warning though.